# Facebook complete logout from android app that uses the Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, logout

I have a problem with the Facebook SDK for Android: basically I have an app X that uses the Facebook SDK to login (since I also have the "Facebook" app for Android installed on my smartphone, it uses its native login screen to access) . 
In this way, if I login from my app X via facebook SDK, I find myself also logged in in the  "Facebook" app for Android.

Now the question arises: if I want to disconnect from my app X (maybe because I want to change user or because I used the app on another phone not mine), the facebook SDK does not allow the total disconnection from FB, but only from my app X. 
This is a problem because if I open the app "Facebook" for Android, I find myself still connected and if I close and reopen my app X, it notes that there is a FB session opened and It auto connect me with that user.

How can I make complete logout from FB from my app X?

Thanks

Comment: I understand that if I do logout from my app (invalidating my app Access Token), when I reopen the app it will automatically reconnect to FB using the Facebook APP Access Token and creating new Access Token for my app... it's very annoying... is there a method to separate the 2 apps?

Comment: I'm saying this because otherwise my app user must disconnect from Facebook App to change user or to completely logout my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the only method to completely logout facebook is to disable SSO login and use the web version...

Answer (score 1):

Just try to do the following: LoginManager.getInstance().setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.WEB_ONLY)

Pros: LoginManager.getInstance().logOut() works fine in this case.

Cons: the authentication will always appear in a webview dialog.